# Message part size returned by Gmail API does not match the value returned by len()

Tags: python-3.x, gmail-api

I'm reading email messages from a Gmail inbox using Python 3 and the google-api-python-client package.

I'm decoding messages bodies using the `urlsafe_b64decode()` function:

```
msg_body = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(payload_body['data'])
```

Everything works fine with `utf-8` or `ISO-8859-1` encoded messages. However, when the message use a more "complex" charset like `gb2312`, the value in the [size](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments?hl=fr#resource) field does not match the value returned by:

```
len(msg_body)
```

Example with a message part encoded using the `gb2312` charset:

```
>>> payload_body['size']
147
>>> len(msg_body)
168
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you reffering to [sizeEstimate](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages) which is the estimated size in bytes of the message? What makes you think they should return the same result?

Comment: @noogui No, I'm referring to the `size` field which indicate the exact size of each message part: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments?hl=fr#resource

Comment: What is len(payload_body['data'])?  You seem to be comparing b64 encoded with b64 decoded and/or payload bytes with Unicode characters (which is what the Python len() function counts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out it's bug of the Gmail API: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/510